# iOS convert number to iphone 6 equivalent and 6 plus equivalent

Tags: ios, iphone

Lets say I have a 44px x 44px UIView on the iphone 5. What's the formula for converting that to the equivalent pixel size for the iphone 6 and 6 plus??

Like would it be 88 x 88 & 132 x 132 or what?

If I have a 44 x 44 UIView on the iPhone 5, how can I have that same view on 6 and 6 plus proportionately take up the same space on the screen

Comment: [X Y problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Well I know the 6 plus is not exactly 3x the resolution so its not 132 x 132, I just threw that out there as an example. There has to be an existing formula for this problem

Comment: Or a technique that solves it that doesn't require aforementioned formula.  Hard to believe that something like this would have a hard-coded number in it, unless it were one of the system constants.

Comment: The question makes no sense. The iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 both are 2x retina displays so the image size wouldn't change.

Comment: rmaddy, well the width of the iphone 6 is larger than the 5. So if I want 44 x 44 to take up the same size on the 5 as the 6, I need to do a percentage calculation. However, the 6 plus adds extra complexity because its at a different resolution

Comment: The native resolution of the 6 plus isn't exactly 3x, but it *renders* at 3x, so that's what you use for assets

Comment: @MobileMon You need to clarify your question then. The question is not clear that you want the image to take up the same screen width (and height?) percentage. That's very different from how it reads at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
+(float)convertWidthToEquivalentDeviceWidth:(float)width{
    float sizedToWidthDesignedTo = 320.0f;
    float actualWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

    float percentWidth = actualWidth/sizedToWidthDesignedTo;

    return width * percentWidth;

}


+(float)convertHeightToEquivalentDeviceHeight:(float)height{
     float sizedToHeightDesignedTo = 568.0f;
     float actualHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

     float percentHeight = actualHeight/sizedToHeightDesignedTo;

     return height * percentHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width of the screen and divide it to the number you want so you don't need to do code for every single device:

```
viewWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / scaleOfYourChoice
```

Comment: Hmm..not quite sure I understand. Can you spell it out a little more? Like what would 44 x 44 be on each device?

Comment: @MobileMon I assume that you want to have a UIView which size depends on the iPhone size, So the line of code I wrote means that you can create that size depending on the device is running, so if you are running in a 320px-width device, you could have a 40px view setting scaleOfYourChoice (see the line of code) with a value of 8 (320/8=40). Then in another screen it would look just bigger, but at the same proportion you had (I don't know if this explanation was better :S)

Answer (score 0):

Setup constraints for top, leading, trailing space and aspect ratio.

The leading and trailing constraints will make your view change width on bigger phones and the aspect ratio constraint will adjust its height accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you do: you set the frame to be 44x44. Then you do nothing else whatsoever. UIKit coordinates are not in pixels; the problem is dealt with for you.

Use `-[UIScreen nativeScale]` if you're curious how many physical pixels are inside a point. That's effectively the number your UIKit coordinates are being multiplied by to make pixels.

If you instead want your view always to be, say, 36% of the available space, use an equal widths `NSLayoutConstraint` with a multiplier of `0.36`.

Comment: If the down voter can comment, that'd be helpful. The poster states he "want[s his view] to take up the same size on the 5 as the 6". This is the correct answer for that constraint.

Comment: Seems it's a bit more complicated than you describe: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: proportionately the same size, as in percentage wise. Not using constraints/auto layout. Like it takes up 25% on this screen, it should also take up 25% on this screen. I guess its just simple math but wasn't sure if the different resolution changed anything

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's not. Put a 44x44pt view on screen on any iPhone you can find. Find a ruler and measure it.

Comment: So are the pixels actually larger on the six, or does it just scale automatically to the number of available pixels?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it scales so that 1pt — the UIKit unit — is always (give or take) the same physical size. It's 1px on an original iPhone, 2px on a 4s, 5, 5s and 6, and approximately 2.7px on a 6+ (it draws at three times then pixel scales the output down a little so that points are very close to the usual size).

Comment: @MobileMon as per rmaddy then, I found the question confusing. Use `NSLayoutConstraint`s.